Path-connected components and homotopy equivalence of topological space $\Delta$ of ordered triangles in $\mathbb{C}$.
I am having trouble with the following question, particularly the intuition behind it and visualizing the described space.

Consider the subspace $\Delta$ of $\mathbb{C}^{3}$, of ordered triangles in $\mathbb{C}$ given by \begin{equation*} \Delta := \{(p, q, r) \in \mathbb{C}^{3} \mid p, q, r \text{ are not collinear in } \mathbb{C}\}. \end{equation*}

The two problems I've looked at are

(1) Prove that $\Delta$ consists of two path-connected components.


(2) Let $U = \{(0, q, r) \in \Delta \mid |q| = |r| = |q-r| = 1\}$, prove that $\Delta$ is homotopy equivalent to $U$.

For (1), I know that $p, q, r \in \mathbb{C}$ not being collinear means $\frac{q - p}{r - q} \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$. Hence $p \neq q$. Then we have a 'plane' in $\mathbb{C}^{3}$ where $p = q$, which divides $X$ into path-connected parts. Is my intuition correct on this?
For (2), it seems that $U$ is homeomorphic to a unit circle. But I don't know how to show that $\Delta$ is homotopy equivalent to $U$ (not necessarily by giving an explicit deformation retract but rather by a description).
Any help is appreciated.

$U$ being homeomorphic to a unit circle contradicts (1)!

@QiaochuYuan I see, thank you!  I know that $U$ is the subset of equilateral triangles with side $1$ and has the origin as a vertex. But I can't see what it would be homeomorphic to.


I know that $p, q, r \in \mathbb{C}$ not being collinear means $\frac{q - p}{r - q} \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \mathbb{R}$. Hence $p \neq q$. Then we have a 'plane' in $\mathbb{C}^{3}$ where $p = q$, which divides $X$ into path-connected parts. Is my intuition correct on this?

This description is not symmetric in $p, q, r$ which is reason for suspicion. The condition $p = q$ alone doesn't divide anything into path-connected components, since the complement $\mathbb{C}^2 \setminus \{ p = q \}$ is connected, unlike the case of $\mathbb{R}$. Generally, the complement of a codimension-$2$ submanifold of a connected manifold remains connected, so only codimension-$1$ submanifolds can divide anything into two pieces.
Anyway, $\Delta$ is the configuration space of ordered triangles in the plane (we don't really have to bring $\mathbb{C}$ into it). Ordered triangles have two orientations, depending on whether the vertices $p, q, r$ are ordered clockwise or counterclockwise. Those are the two connected components. Formally you can show that the orientation of an ordered triangle with vertices $p, q, r \in \mathbb{C}$ is given by the sign of the determinant
$$\det \left[ \begin{array}{ccc} \text{Re}(p) & \text{Im}(p) & 1 \\ \text{Re}(q) & \text{Im}(q) & 1 \\ \text{Re}(r) & \text{Im}(r) & 1 \end{array} \right] \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Moreover $p, q, r$ are collinear iff this determinant is zero, so it cuts out the complement of $\Delta$. (Edit: Of course this determinant is just twice the signed area of the triangle, I'd forgotten.)
Now if you want to convince yourself that (1) is true you need to visualize how to connect any two ordered triangles with the same orientation by a path in $\Delta$. (Hint: step 1 is to translate one to the other so that their first vertices match.)
For (2) you can do it by a sequence of deformation retracts which are not so bad to visualize in terms of triangles. Step 1 is to continuously translate all three vectors by $-p$; this deformation retracts onto the subspace cut out by $p = 0$. Step 2 is to continuously scale $q$ until $|q| = 1$. Step 3 is to continuously scale $r$ until $|r| = 1$. So far the only difficulty is to check that a triangle stays a triangle throughout this process, and we've already gotten all the way down from the $6$-dimensional manifold $\Delta$ to the $2$-dimensional manifold
$$\{ (0, q, r) : |q| = |r| = 1, q \neq r, -r \}$$
of pairs of points on a circle which are not equal to each other or to each other's antipodes. This again has two connected components depending on whether $r$ is clockwise or counterclockwise of $q$. The final step is to scale $q - r$ until $|q - r| = 1$; this gets us all the way down to $U$, which consists of equilateral triangles with one vertex at the origin and the other two vertices on the unit circle. This is now a $1$-dimensional manifold consisting of two copies of $S^1$, one for each orientation; to be explicit, a homeomorphism is given by sending to the pair consisting of its orientation and $q$ (and you could also use $r$).
